# Searching text elements in XSL and creating a hyperlink

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help getting links returned in XML format to display on a website. Currently I'm using

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Summary/text">
    <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="self::*"/>
    </p>
```

This grabs each paragraph and indents it properly. This works great, except for links we get. I'm a bit confused on what to do. The text I need displayed as a hyperlink is showing as a separate paragraph like so:

```
    <a href=http://www.google.com</a>
```

So I thought I'd call a template to do this.

```
       <xsl:template name="hyperlink">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'href=http://')">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 8, 500)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="self::*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know if $text or `'href=http://'` is right. When I try to use `contains('<a href')` to test, I get errors.  I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.  I don't think I'm using the correct statements to make this work.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem appears when you get links that are not quite valid (like the one you cited in your post) ?

Comment: Can you please show us a sample of your xml input together with expected output? Also what version of XSLT are you using and what engine?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the actual length of the *href* string using *string-length*:

```
substring($text, 8, string-length($text) - 13)
```